# Create multiple lookup item on one SharePoint list and send the result to another SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, microsoft-flow, power-automate, office-365-groups

I am really having trouble around here.

I have 2 SharePoint list items, one is the populated list from entries of employees and the other is a submission monitoring of the first list showing the total number of submissions per location in each column.

I used the second list as a lookup for the first and select multiple selection possible.

List no.1
[image]

List no. 2
[image]

Its easy to count the [Generated] column if the lookup I used on List no.1 is not multiple selection but once multiple selection is selected, the count is not possible anymore using the lookup procedure. This is where I am having a hard time.

1. I need help for any work around to count the other columns on list no.1 and have it appear on list no.2
2. If the location mentioned in list no.2 did not select on each column on list no.1, I want to monitor that as well as [None Selected].

I will appreciate any assistance on this.

Thank you very much.

Regards,
Glenn

Answer (score 0):

Per my research,there is no other way to achieve this.

And this is the OOB way that If the location mentioned in list hasn't been selected, it will show 0.